# Can I revert this question back to un-Community-Wiki?

Tags: support, status-completed

I'm not sure what I did [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96761/how-does-the-vaccinator-work). Because the other answerer also talked about some parts of the vaccinator, I found it somewhat redundant to do it myself as well, and just referenced his post.

I also hit community wiki button because of this, and as such, it's stuck at community wiki.

Can some mod help revert it back?

Also, all revisions are by me, I made a mistake.

Comment: You can just flag it as "Other" with a description for this.

Comment: @MatthewRead You can? Do mods have an "Undo CW" button now? (Back in beta there wasn't any way to do this.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yep, that changed a while ago.

Comment: @MatthewRead Sweet. I've been treating that checkbox like *deadly poison* for so long, it'll be nice to relax, especially on the mobile site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.